# Alternatives for @formula annotation or sql decrypt function

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have an issue with the `@Formula` annotation in Hibernate when I'm trying to decrypt a password column (PWD_COL) using a key (which is retrieved from a properties file)

The code:

```
@Formula("decrypt(PWD_COL, '" + MyKeys.DECRYPT_KEY + "')")
private String myPwd;
```

I am trying to get the DECRYPT_KEY from another property file.

I am getting an error:

> The value for annotation attribute Formula.value must be a constant
>   expression

Alternately, is there a way to mimic the SQL decrypt function in Java?

Note: Please read the password field as just another value. The eventual purpose of this exercise is for something far less important but nevertheless needs to be encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a `@Formula` annotation has to be valid SQL since it is passed more or less directly to the underlying DB.

This also explains why your idea won't work - the DB will have no notion of  the `MyKeys` class.

You could insert the key in a DB table and `select` it from there in the `@Formula` but security-wise that might not be a particularly sane idea...

What you *really* should be doing (or actually not doing) is to avoid storing passwords, but rather store hashes of passwords and then compare those hashes with the hash of whatever credentials your user presents. That moves encryption/hashing to Java/memory and avoids the embarassment when somebody steals your database, guesses the weak password or bruteforces the encryption and posts it all on pastebin!

Cheers,

Comment: Appreciate the advice but decrypting the password is just a mock idea that I was playing around with. The eventual purpose is for something else.

Comment: Also MyKeys.DECRYPT_KEY works when I give a static value in the java class itself.

Comment: Also I would be grateful if you could suggest a way to mimic the sql decrypt function in java

Comment: Decrypting in Java in in principle possible, but depends on the crypto algorithm used. It would probably be going too far trying to reimplement that in Java, so I'd suggest doing both encryption and decryption in Java. How to do that is entirely a new question - you should be able to find lots of answers and references to that area here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not what you are looking for but let me give you a advice about store password on database, maybe you should change your mindset about how to work with passwords.

You should not decrypt passwords on database because security reasons, so if someone lost password they should create a new one.

To validate login and related tasks you should take the password from the form, encrypt it and compare with the encrypted on in database.

If you really want to keep doing in this way use @formula with valid sql values.

Comment: Thanks Igor. But say it is not a password field and some other value that is not that important, can we overcome this problem ?

Comment: Sure I can compare the encrypted values, but initially I just use sql encrypt (using a key) to store in the DB. Now, can I mimic this sql encrypt function in java to encypt the password from the form  and then compare?

Comment: if it is not important you do not need to encrypt it. If you really need to decrypt it and still can not use @formula you can write your own decrypt function and add it the the the get. Exemple: getMYPwd() { decrypt();return myPwd;}

Comment: you do not need to mimic sql encrypt in java to compare, just use the sql encrypt again in the value that came from the form on the login validate sql function.